# Outlook Add-in Ribbon Margin between Controls

Tags: windows, outlook, ms-office, add-in

I developed a Add-In for Microsoft Office with some controls in the Ribbon. Problem is that there seems to be no option for a "margin" or something for the controls.

Is there a way to put some space between them?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, the Fluent UI doesn't provide any margin-related properties. You need to assemble controls into groups or use the separator which represents a separator line between controls. You can find the full list of controls in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)